# Have I bricked my minecraft world by TP'ing out of bounds? (1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was testing on my Minecraft save with health effects and wanted to test my resistance ability with the Void. Naturally I tp'd down to some ridiculous y level, which NBT Explorer said was -1E31. Immediately, Minecraft stopped responding and eventually crashed. Here's what I've tried, reopening the save after every attempt:

- Changing my UUID's Pos NBT tag in NBT Explorer to 100
- Removing my UUID player data altogether
- Optimising the world in-game

Each time, I'm met with 'Joining world...' followed by (Not Responding).
Before you ask, no, I didn't make any backups. I wasn't expecting it to be *this* bricked.

My guess is that I generated a region file in the map that breaks everything, but I have no idea how to identify the culprit file. Is there any way to save my world?

Comment: This bug is responsible for it: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-123587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a singleplayer map, you not only need to remove or change your UUID's position, but also the 'Player' in level.dat, which is whoever opens the world from the Singleplayer menu.